Conditionally required attribute in API Platform
I'm new to API Platform and I want to ask if there's a way to conditionally require an attribute of an entity. For example, I have an entity User with two attributes, HasCar and CarModel. CarModel will only be required if HasCar = true
This is my user class example but I'm not sure how to go forward with a conditional required property
class User {

 #[ORM\Column('name: HasCar')]
 private bool $hasCar = '';

 #[ORM\Column('name: CarModel')]
 //#[ApiProperty(required:true)] only if $hasCar = true
 private string $carModel = '';

}


You can't define properties in a class as "conditional" in the same way as it is done with procedural programming(i.e if statement).
You can try this instead...
class User{

protected $hasCar;
protected $carModel;

public function setCar(bool $hasCar): void
{
  $this->hasCar = $hasCar;
}

public function getCar(): ?bool
{
  return $this->hasCar;
}

public function setCarModel(string $carModel): void
{

  if(!$this->hasCar)
  {
    $carModel = NULL ;
  }
  $this->carModel = $carModel

}

public function getCarModel(): ?string
{
  return $this->carModel ;
}


}


#[ApiResource(
    shortName: 'Password reset',
    operations: [
        new Post(
            uriTemplate: '/request_password_reset',
            openapi: new Operation(
                summary: 'Request password reset',
                description: 'Request password reset'
            ),
            processor: RequestPasswordResetProcessor::class,
        ),
    ]
)]
class RequestPasswordReset
{
    #[Assert\When(
        expression: '!this.phone',
        constraints: [
            new Assert\NotBlank,
            new Assert\Type('string'),
            new Assert\Email,
        ],
    )]
    public string $email;

    #[Assert\When(
        expression: '!this.email',
        constraints: [
            new Assert\NotBlank,
            new Assert\Type('string'),
            new AssertPhoneNumber,
        ],
    )]
    public string $phone;
}

